# Conditional type is not being narrowed by if/else branch

Tags: typescript, typeof, narrowing, conditional-types, type-narrowing

I'm trying to write a function with a callback whose argument type depends on the argument of a parameter to the non-callback function.

I tried inferring the type using `typeof` which narrows correctly for new declarations in the branch but does not narrow the callback.

```js
type Argument = "Foo" | "Bar";
type CallbackArgument<T extends Argument> = T extends "Foo" ? "One" : T extends "Bar" ? "Two" : never;

function foo(arg: Argument, callback: (callbackArg: CallbackArgument<typeof arg>) => void) {
    if (arg === "Foo") {
        callback("Two") // Works, callbackArg hasn't narrowed.
        const two: CallbackArgument<typeof arg> = "Two" // Error, narrowing seems to work.
    }
}
```

Since `typeof arg` has clearly narrowed to `"Foo"` I would expect `callbackArg` to correctly narrow to `"One"` within the branch as it does for new declarations (like `two`).

I'm using Typescript 3.5.2.

Comment: @GOTO0 What do you mean by 
"it does correctly narrow"? `callback` accepts either `One` or `Two` as an argument,  that is what OP wants to prevent. They want to narrow `callback` to only accept `One` based on the check  `arg === "Foo"`

Comment: @GOTO0 not really, you get an error on the `callback("Two")` invocation but also on `callback("One")`. So you won't be able to call it with anything without a type assertion. I'm guessing this is over simplified so not sure if this helps for the real use case

Comment: @GOTO0 I should have written that the solution you proposed was my original attempt. As Titian mentions, this doesn't narrow the type at all and makes all calls to `callback` invalid.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson Yes, that's true. Going to delete my comments now.

Answer (score 2):

Narrowing works on single variables. Typescript does not have the concept of related variables/parameters that can be narrowed together.

The only thing you can do is use a discriminated tuple as the argument, narrow the tuple and spread the arguments from it:

```
type Argument = "Foo" | "Bar";
type CallbackArgument<T extends Argument> = T extends "Foo" ? "One" : T extends "Bar" ? "Two" : never;

function foo(args: ["Foo", (p: "One") => void] |  ["Bar", (p: "Two") => void]) {
    if (args[0] === "Foo") {
        const [arg, callback] = args;
        callback("Two") // Error now
        const two: CallbackArgument<typeof arg> = "Two" // Error
    }
}
```

Comment: That's unfortunate. Even though this doesn't solve my problem I think there are ways of making this strategy nicer by defining a discriminated union with properties `argument: T` and `callback(arg: CallbackArgument<T>): void`.

Then it is possible to define `foo(args: ArgUnion<"Foo"> | ArgUnion<"Bar">)` and pattern match to get the correct narrowing for the callback. This avoids destructuring while also forcing correct callback argument.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson yes, using an object instead of a tuple is better for the implementation, but that will change the call site.