# Can conditional type determine related type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use conditional type with generic to determine another type.
But Type narrow for this conditional type.
For more specific, I want to narrow conditional type based on parameter's type.

```js
export function foo<T extends "a" | "b">(parameter: T) {
    type Foo = T extends "a" ? 1 : 2;
    let foo: Foo;
    if (parameter === "a") foo = 1;
    else foo = 2;
}
```

I think this is related to [Conditional type is not being narrowed by if/else...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271163/conditional-type-is-not-being-narrowed-by-if-else-branch#comment101079465_57271163), but I don't know the exact reason.

And is there best practice in these situation?(want to decide type based on parameter's type)

ps. I don't want to use Discriminated unions because when I use it, I have to add parameter like below.

```js
type A = { type: "a"; foo?: 1 };
type B = { type: "b"; foo?: 2 };
export function foo<T extends A | B>(parameter: T) {
  //parameter is not strict. (foo can be one of parameter)
  if (parameter.type === "a") parameter.foo = 1;
  else parameter.foo = 2;
}
```

Above details are my final try.
I searched various documents about that, but I could't find the documents that explains the reason of this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is best practice, but you can always override the type system using `as`: `foo = 1 as T extends "a" ? 1 : 2`. You're basically telling the type system that you know something it doesn't (namely, how `foo`'s type relates to `parameter`'s).

Comment: Generics and control flow don't play nicely together and neither do generics and conditional types; the "best practice" is probably to avoid both control flow and generics by refactoring to use *object indexing*, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5Qg2N).  Does that fully address the question?  If so I will write up an answer explaining with documentation links about the limitations; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz your suggestion looks nice and easy. I couldn't think that way. It is what I want. It is the best way to use conditional type without type assertion I have seen. please write answer if you can. Thanks jcalz! 
ps. I have one more question, can't I use your way with if statement like I used in my question.

Comment: I have explained in detail in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Narrowing is of (the type of) *values*, not of *types*: so, after `foo` has been declared, even if its declared type depends on the type of `parameter`, later narrowing `parameter` will not and indeed should not "retroactively" narrow `foo`.

Here is a way I could make your code work without resorting to discriminated unions or similar, namely by declaring `foo` inside the guarded blocks that narrow `parameter` (I have changed some names in my code for convenience):

```
type Param = "a" | "b";

type Foo<P extends Param> =
  P extends "a" ? 1 :
  P extends "b" ? 2 : never;

export function test_foo(p: Param) {
  p;  // (parameter) p: Param

  // this would *not* be narrowed!
  let foo: Foo<typeof p>;  // let foo: 1 | 2

  if (p === "a") {
    p;  // (parameter) p: "a"

    // this *does* get narrowed!
    let foo: Foo<typeof p>;  // let foo: 1

    foo = 1;
    //foo = 2;  // ERROR: Type '2' is not assignable to type '1'.
  }
  else {
    p;  // (parameter) p: "b"

    // this *does* get narrowed!
    let foo: Foo<typeof p>;  // let foo: 2

    //foo = 1;  // ERROR: Type '1' is not assignable to type '2'.
    foo = 2;
  }
}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWygXigIjpqAfLAI0wG4AoM0SKAMQHs6AeGKCAD2AgDsATAZ1iIUAPnRkosVh278sOKAH4oARigAucZPadeAzMUVQATOqhcIANwgJyZdmDoJgUAGYBXLgGNgASzpcoTj5gAH0XBgAKMDVBJGQASigAb00wEgkAegyoKKFkCE4EROjYlApM7OAACx8BAHc6NwAbHigAKi46YDaoQmguRAQ6OogeAEJNJoLXBhj6JioIOhcoMGF0qCyoKedwuhjVAiNyqB8VqPQ0DGxMRJSJCTSKnLA8gutimJuT5+ra9p4dAgfB6AHNpgMEEMRuNNBIdjN9rQGIxFstVutngi9gcfoj0CpyA9Nhk9gSjBstgBRABKNIA8jSYgAVcDQADkRnZpwEnWccD4fB8oIGhCmgTogTZUHZynZADpNABfTQQJp8aD3B5PEkvN6FT5ETB4rZ-ARtQHAsEQwbDUYTYnY2bIhZs9FrSnZJ1I45wklkjDKT1QWkMplQVnUWXc-58qACoUiuBi6DASWLGVcxXEgPGIlQFUqoA)

Comment: This works (and I upvoted it), but I think it's also not super useful. (1) There isn't a single `let foo` declaration at the function scope, so you could just skip all this and do `if (p === "a") { const foo = 1 ; ... }` and it would function the same. (2) As written, you can't use Param in conjunction with any other type on the signature (e.g. by returning a type `Param extends "a" ? 1 : 2`. You'd have to make the method generic on `P extends Param`, at which point it doesn't work anymore. (3) So basically, the Foo magic only works on independent, isolated branches — where it's not needed.

Comment: Hi @yshavit , I agree with you, indeed a `let foo: Foo<P>` where `P extends Param` is not resolved at all by TS, whether before or after the guard on `p`.  But here the purpose was just to provide the requested explanation about narrowing.

Comment: Yup, understood. I think zooming out a bit, OP should think about what they're actually trying to accomplish. If what they're trying to do is "some internal if-else logic, but using a local variable that's declared outside the if-else", then I think the best answer is "don't do that — just use separate variables without fancy conditional types". If what they're trying to do is "return a type conditional on the input" (or something similar, like also taking in a function whose input depends on the first input) then I think they'll need to use `as` to sidestep the type checker.

Comment: (That said, I'm not a super TS expert, so there could be some other case I'm missing!)

Comment: I suspect the OP is aware of all that, they just want a clearer explanation of the way narrowing works.  That said, using `as` except in *construction*, or, even worse, `any`, is always the *last* resort: I rather find more common using type assertions because TS (still) *does* have some limitations...  But in the more general scheme of things, IMHO you risk to be "theorizing" too much: learning the spec is a must, but the concrete patterns should indeed come as necessity *out of* the coding (the code structure) itself...

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, in my previous comment by "type assertions" I meant specifically the *Non-null Assertion Operator*: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-

Answer (score 0):

Currently in TypeScript [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) does not affect [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  So while `if`/`else` statements or `switch`/`case` statements or `?`/`:` expressions can serve to narrow the apparent types of *values*, they cannot do anything to re-constrain generic *types*.  Inside

```
function foo<T extends "a" | "b">(parameter: T) {
    type Foo = T extends "a" ? 1 : 2;
    let foo: Foo;
    if (parameter === "a") foo = 1;
    else foo = 2;
}
```

the check `(parameter === "a")` narrows the type of `parameter` from `T` to something like `T & "a"`.  But `T` itself does not change or become constrained to `"a"`.  And thus the type `Foo` stays the generic [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `T extends "a" ? 1 : 2` instead of being evaluated to `1`.

It might seem obvious that checking `parameter === "a"` should make `T` equal to `"a"`, but it's actually tricky to get this right, and there are many situations in which such an assumption would be unsafe.

There are multiple open feature requests asking for some way to support this better:

- [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) points out the general problem with generic conditional types and control flow analysis
- [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) suggests allowing certain safe control-flow related changes to generic types
- [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) suggests restricting generic type arguments to be exactly one of a specified set so that checking a generic value will definitely imply something about the generic type parameter.

Until and unless these or similar features are implemented, though, this is a limitation of TypeScript and we have to work around it.

---

One way to deal with this is to give up on control flow analysis and conditional types entirely and refactor so that your different cases are represented as a generic *indexing operation* into an object, and your types can be written as [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  That is, change code that looks like `v === "a" ? x : v === "b" ? y : v === "c" ? z : undefined` to `{a: x, b: y, c: z}[v]`.  TypeScript *is* able to perform generic indexing operations in the type system.  In your case the refactoring looks like

```
function foo<T extends "a" | "b">(parameter: T) {
  type Foo = { a: 1, b: 2 }[T]
  let foo: Foo = ({ a: 1, b: 2 } as const)[parameter];
}
```

(where the [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) is only used because otherwise TS will infer the type `{a: number, b: number}` instead of `{a: 1, b: 2}`.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIwIYBMBic4B4AqiApgB5RFjoDOiARKrYgD53K0B8AFAA6oBOqALZFyfAFyJ8ASkQBvAFCJEUAJ7ciibHEQBeScTIVqdBogD8iAIyIJAJgDcixABsRiYDglbHSmMEQ8-EIiRHy6Onr0tDIe2nqWPsTOVBqxuogO8gC+8vKgkLAI7jgEBuSUNFHMrByBAsKiEtJyTqrqmjjpsoioEpYANCh2iFkA2vgAuk6uUMVwXp16nN29VoPIw1k9NBAIVFBSo7z1IXwTjllAA)